# How to use cver - verilog simulator on Ubuntu - 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: command-line

I want to use `cver - verilog simulator`, but I cannot find much info/documentation files about it. Could you please help me, how can I cver to simulate verilog code through terminal? Also, how similar is cver to Icarus?

Thank you

(Excuse me, for any mistakes in frame the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some bad news about this [`gplcver` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gplcver). According to [Debian package tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gplcver) it is orphaned since 2009.

In anyway you can start with its short man-page - locally by `man cver` or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/cver.1.html) or using its built-in help by `cver -h`.

---

In newer Ubuntu versions there is a special meta-package named [`electronics-fpga-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/electronics-fpga-dev), you can try its components on your Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. One of them is a package named [`verilator`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/verilator), it looks [more mature](https://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilator).

Comment: Thanks! N0rbert. I'll surely try